# Message: Undefined property CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Vi codigo repetido en varios controladores. Creo un controller common para ser llamado cada vez que lo precise y asi no repetir el mismo codigo en dif, controllers.

Entonces creo un controlador (supongamos A y B donde B esta la funcion que preciso), con su respectiva funcion.

Entonces en el controller A instancio a B

```
require APPPATH . 'controllers/admin/B.php'; 
$B = new B();
$data = $B->traemenu($this->session->userdata('id_rol'),$this->session>userdata('codigo_modulo'));
```

Pero me da el siguiente error: **Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php**

Leí por ahi que podia poner en Libraries mi funcion. Entonces ahora lo tengo asi:

En el controlador B en el contructor:

```
$this->load->library('B');
```

Y asi pretendo traer los datos:

```
$data = $this->B->traemenu($this->session->userdata('id_rol'),$this->session->userdata('codigo_modulo'));
```

y este es mi Controller B:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class B{
  public function __construct()
       {
       }

  function traemenu($id,$codmod)
  {
    //menues
   try {
      $respuestaMenu = $this->m_menus->get_menus($id,$codmod); //CUIL + CODIGO MODULO
      if($respuestaMenu['mensajeErrorDB']==""){
        if($respuestaMenu['existeMenu']==true){
          $data['menu'] = $respuestaMenu['rows']->result();
          $data['menuactivo'] =  lang('codigo_modulo_admin');
          $this->load->view('admin/v_admin_encabezado',$data);
        }else{
          throw new Exception(lang('mensaje_errores_menu_noexiste'));
        }
      }else{
        throw new Exception($respuestaMenu['mensajeErrorDB']);
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      show_error($e->getMessage());
    }
    //fin menues...
  }
}
```

Pero de esta forma me da el error que puse en el titulo del post. Ya no se que hacer.

Comment: El problema es que no están definidas las propiedades y funciones de la clase. En el caso de Controller B cada que ocupas `$this` es una propiedad o función dentro de la misma clase. Dicho de otra manera: `class B{ }` no tiene las propiedades `m_menus` ni `load`

Comment: @RafaelBautista como puedo solucionarlo?